# Maven jacoco excludes does not work

Tags: maven, configuration, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

```
 <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- remove haltOnFailure to purposely fail build once we recover coverage back to 70% -->
                    <haltOnFailure>false</haltOnFailure>
                    <rules>
                        <rule>
                            <element>CLASS</element>
                            <limits>
                                <limit>
                                    <counter>LINE</counter>
                                    <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                    <minimum>0.70</minimum>
                                </limit>
                                <limit>
                                    <counter>BRANCH</counter>
                                    <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                    <minimum>0.70</minimum>
                                </limit>
                            </limits>
                            <excludes>
                                <!-- exclude domain objects -->
                                <exclude>com/path/to/classes/**/*</exclude>                               
                            </excludes>
                        </rule>
                    </rules>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>check</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

**Expected behaviour:** The HTML report at target/site/jacoco/index.html does not contain a row for com/path/to/classes

**Actual behaviour:** The HTML report at target/site/jacoco/index.html includes a row for com/path/to/classes which causes the coverage to be reported as (in my case) 32%, proving that this package is being included **and should not be**.

[image]

I must be doing something wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can completely exclude files from *instrumentation/analysis/reports* on `configuration`'s `excludes` node

```
<configuration>
    <excludes>
        <exclude>com/path/to/classes/**/*</exclude>
    </excludes>
</configuration>
```

Excludes specified on the `rule` node ignore the classes excluded for that rule only

Comment: Thanks - did not notice that I had erronously included my `<excludes>` block within my `<rules>` block instead of under my `<configuation>` block. Thanks for the pointer (although my config needed to be in an `<exclude>` line nested inside the `<excludes>` parent in order to work).